# Is it possible to run two scripts instead of sending two queries in Elasticsearch?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I have a simple question.

I'm trying to append "tags" to an Elasticsearch array.

I find it hard to wrap my head around the scripting function in Elasticsearch, but found two queries that does the job, but both has to be called. Meaning that PHP (in my case), has to send two POST requests to the Elasticsearch database, which I think *might* cause some problems in the long term.

I think it would be safer to send it all in just one query.

The queries bellow is to update the `votes` of an array called `tags` from `1`, to `2`. I'm sure there are better ways of doing this than I have done.

### Here are the queries I use:

I'm not sure why this `votes: 2` are there, but it seems to do the job of deleting the tag. As I said, I find it hard to wrap my head around scripting in Elasticsearch.

```
POST /db2/links/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "for(int i=0;i<ctx._source.tags.size();i++){if(ctx._source.tags[i].name==\"tagname\"){ctx._source.tags.remove(i)}}",
    "params": {
      "votes": 2
    }
  }
}
```

This query is for appending the tag to the `tags` array of the document

```
POST /db2/links/1/_update
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.tags.add(params.appendtags)",
    "params": {
      "appendtags": {
        "name": "tagname",
        "votes": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any ways to easily combine these two scripts together in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [bulk api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update) to make multiple updates in a single call.

```
POST _bulk
{"update":{"_id":"1","_type":"links","_index":"db2","retry_on_conflict":3}}
{"script":{"inline":"for(int i=0;i<ctx._source.tags.size();i++){if(ctx._source.tags[i].name==\"tagname\"){ctx._source.tags.remove(i)}}","params":{"votes":2}}}
{"update":{"_id":"1","_type":"links","_index":"db2","retry_on_conflict":3}}
{"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.tags.add(params.appendtags)","params":{"appendtags":{"name":"tagname","votes":2}}}}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! I'm guessing the `"retry_on_conflict": 3` means that it will try again 3 times if it fails? If so, does the whole bulk abort, or just the line?
In my case, it is really important that both scripts are being ran. Either none, or all.

Comment: The whole bulk won't abort only one that fails. For both or none case , you have to handle at application level.